# RuntimeBinderException because of null reference in Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, razor, visual-studio-2015

Just opened an account because of this one.

I have created an empty Web project on Visual Studio (without MVC, Forms or Web API), and while debugging this line:

```
@if (Session["GenCpN"] != null) { @Session["GenCpN"] }
```

of a layout file (_GenLayout.cshtml) for my default.cshtml, I run into the following exception:

```
Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2146233088
  Message=Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference
  Source=Anonymously Hosted DynamicMethods Assembly
  StackTrace:
       at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object , String , Object )
       at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute3[T0,T1,T2,TRet](CallSite site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1, T2 arg2)
       at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object , String , Object )
       at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute3[T0,T1,T2,TRet](CallSite site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1, T2 arg2)
       at ASP._Page__GenLayout_cshtml.Execute() in C:\Users\PJ\OneDrive\Documents\Dev\BWC\WebApp\_GenLayout.cshtml:line 7
       at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy()
       at System.Web.WebPages.WebPage.ExecutePageHierarchy(IEnumerable`1 executors)
       at System.Web.WebPages.WebPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()
       at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage)
       at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer)
       at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.<>c__DisplayClass3.<RenderPageCore>b__2(TextWriter writer)
       at System.Web.WebPages.HelperResult.WriteTo(TextWriter writer)
       at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageExecutingBase.WriteTo(TextWriter writer, HelperResult content)
       at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.Write(HelperResult result)
       at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.RenderSurrounding(String partialViewName, Action`1 body)
       at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.PopContext()
       at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage)
       at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageHttpHandler.ProcessRequestInternal(HttpContextBase httpContext)
  InnerException:
```

By the way if it helps, Visual Studio breaks on the closing bracket when I use one line for each statement. Also, I remember my code working before - among other changes - I added a new web.config file in a subfolder of a subfolder (to add a handler. I deleted the file but it still doesn't work).

I imagine this needs to be answered by a pro but I appreciate any answers,

Thank you!

**UPDATE** 1: I have reverted several changes and deleted several files and I still get this error in this file. I also deleted and re-wrote default.cshtml and _GenLayout.cshtml, still nothing. This has affected the solution in a non-visible way. Have I discovered a bug?

**UPDATE** 2: It turns out that the problem disappears once I remove a later line that refers to a custom class but I still can't understand why the specific error occurs. The line I remove is:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="@App.uri("arg1", "arg2")" />
```

Comment: What is in _GenLayout.cshtml:line 7 ?

Comment: @MikeBrind _GenLayout.cshtml is the layout file for default.cshtml. My mistake, I just edited the question. Of course default.cshtml contains `@{ Layout = "~/_GenLayout.cshtml"; }`.

Comment: So what is on line 7 of _GenLayout.cshtml?

Comment: @MikeBrind `@if (Session["GenCpN"] != null) { @Session["GenCpN"] }`

Answer (score 0):

The OP's "UPDATE 2" inspired me to look outside of the signposted error in my own circumstance with a null RuntimeBinderException, and I fixed my bug.

Rather than fretting at the line indicated in the exception stack trace (which was fine), **look for nulls elsewhere (above or below the line indicated by the stack trace)**.

My case was as simple as in some circumstances, the `ViewBag.Title` wasn't set, and therefore it was `null` when I tried to use it for inclusion in the meta-description.